# how to save view as an image to the SD card

Tags: android, image, printing, save, sd-card

My app creates a puzzle grid using table layout, tablerows and textviews.  I want a user to be able to save this grid to the SD card so that it can be printed or copied or loaded onto another device.

How do you save a view so that when it's printed it will look like it does on the android screen?

Comment: You want the file to be printable, but you also want be able to load the file back in and restore game state? I don't think you can have both in a single file format.

Comment: The primary goal is for the user to print the grid.  I don't need to load it back into my app.  It would be nice to allow the user to save the file and copy it.