# Save the wallpaper of an Android device as a picture

Tags: java, android, image

I need to write a program that gets the current wallpaper of an android device and save it to the images folder.

The problem is that I cannot find any information on how to convert the Drawable to a JPEG/PNG

This is my code:

```
android.graphics.drawable.Drawable currentWallpaper = getWallpaper();
```

How do I convert this Drawable into a JPEG/PNG file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080133/how-to-save-view-as-an-image-to-the-sd-card), take a look at http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/30676.aspx. This discusses basically rendering your Drawable on a Canvas backed by a bitmap. You can then save the Bitmap to file using [Bitmap.compress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use getWallpaper() as it is [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getWallpaper%28%29).

Use [WallpaperManager#getDrawable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getDrawable%28%29) instead:

```
WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance();
Drawable d = wpm.getDrawable ();
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
```